# Clarification on "antd doesn't work well on mobile"

Tags: antd, antd-mobile

*(Please note that i'm aware of the existence of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920892/ant-design-antd-vs-antd-mobile-for-non-native-mobile-web-development), but it seems pretty outdated and apparently I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment there)*

I'm considering using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/) for a new project, but one [question](https://ant.design/docs/react/faq#antd-doesn't-work-well-in-mobile.) in the FAQ section really caught my eye:

> **antd doesn't work well in mobile.**
>
> Please check And Design Mobile for details. antd has not been optimized to do so. You may try react-component, those repositories which start with 'm-' 'rn-' are designed for mobile.

What does it mean that "it doesn't work well"? Is it a problem with performance, support of touch events, responsiveness of the components?

The official documentation really doesn't give any more details than that, and I cannot find any useful information on the [Ant Design Mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/) site that could help me figure out which version of antd I should use

I'm planning to build an app that must work well both on desktop and on mobile, and having two separate codebases for each it's not really an option. Would that then disqualify antd as a good choice for my project?

Anyone has more details on what "it doesn't work well" mean in practice?

Comment: Responsiveness of the components mainly, antd was built for desktop mostly. I would pick something else for cross platform apps.